# Calling HomeController action with Dependency injection from Razor Page Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

I have an action in `HomeController` with `Dependency Injecttion` in `Asp.Net Core 2.1.0 Razor Page`.

Action Code

```
    private readonly Test.Data.MyContext _Context;

    public HomeController(Test.Data.MyContext context)
    { _Context = context; }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TypeofAccounts(string at)
    {
        var result = _Context.TypeOfAccounts
            .Where(x => x.AccountType == at)
            .Select(x =>
                new
                {
                    label = x.AccountType,
                    id = x.AccountType
                }
            );

        return Json(result);
    }
```

I would like use this result in various `Razor PageModel`. How can I achieve. Here is sample Razor Page.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly Test.Data.MyContext _Context;
    public IndexModel(Test.Data.MyContext context)
    { _Context = context; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        // Here I want bind HomeController's action.
    }
}
```

I tried with `var ta = new Test.Controllers.HomeController().TypeofAccounts("B001");` but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am not familiar of the practice having an instance of your data context in both view model and controller, you can try this way.

Controller:

```
private readonly Test.Data.MyContext _Context;

public HomeController(Test.Data.MyContext context)
{ _Context = context; }

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult TypeofAccounts(string at)
{
    var result = GetTypeOfAccounts(_Context, at);

    return Json(result);
}

public static IQueryable<dynamic> GetTypeOfAccounts(Test.Data.MyContext context, string at)
{
    var result = context.TypeOfAccounts
        .Where(x => x.AccountType == at)
        .Select(x =>
            new
            {
                label = x.AccountType,
                id = x.AccountType
            }
        );

    return result;
}
```

View Model:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly Test.Data.MyContext _Context;
    public IndexModel(Test.Data.MyContext context)
    { _Context = context; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        // Here I want bind HomeController's action.
        var ta = Test.Controllers.HomeController.GetTypeOfAccounts(_Context, "B001");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach seems to work, but unfortunately i get error "C# The type 'GetTypeOfAccounts' name does not exist in the type 'HomeController'" in View Model.

Comment: Replace `Test.Controllers.` with the correct namespace. I can't see a reason why `GetTypeOfAccounts` would not exist in `HomeController` when I added it as a `public static` member on my example.

Comment: Yes, added correctly, for test purpose i added one more empty public static method. Both gives me same error.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the same concept working for me. https://postimg.cc/py5K7yGb and https://postimg.cc/LJxqhMC3 I am unable to reproduce your error.

Comment: Remove the `new`. The method is static, not an instance method: `var tb = GeneralModel.GetTypeOfAccounts(...)`